onConfigurationChanged isn't called on api 30 and above
My app doesn't rotate when I rotate the phone. This could work on device which api under 30, but can't work on api 30 and above.
I found the problem is onConfigurationChanged  is not called when I rotate the phone.
I've already set android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection|screenLayout" in Manifest.
attached my AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.midea.connect"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <!-- permissions... -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.midea.ConnectApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/connect"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppStyle"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:label,android:allowBackup,android:persistent,android:supportsRtl">

        <meta-data
            android:name="EasyGoClient"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.max_aspect"
            android:value="3" />

        <!-- meta-datas for app keys  -->
        <!-- meta-datas for push keys and icons  -->

        <uses-library
            android:name="android.scanner.library"
            android:required="false" />

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.midea.activity.ModuleWebActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection|screenLayout"
            android:theme="@style/ModuleWebTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.ModuleWebActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.midea.activity.PicViewerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.PicViewerActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.midea.activity.SignatureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

        <activity android:name="com.midea.crop.CropImageActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.CropImageActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tencent.tauth.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="tencent100424468" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.midea.receiver.TimeZoneReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.midea.web.WebService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.meicloud.util.McFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.meicloud.aop.track.TrackReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.meicloud.tracking" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.meicloud.share.McShareActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.share" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>


Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Ensure that your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml has the correct configChanges attribute:
<activity
android:name=".YourActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection"
android:resizeableActivity="true">

and Make sure you have implemented the onConfigurationChanged method in your activity:
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // Handle landscape orientation
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // Handle portrait orientation
    }
}


Since handling configuration changes can sometimes interfere with the activity lifecycle, ensure your activity's lifecycle methods are properly managed

At the end




Remove orientation from the configChanges attribute

thanks for answer. But I have implemented the onConfigurationChanged method, and I added android:resizeableActivity="true". It still doesn't work
